# drupal 7 styling the ajax throbber and progress bar

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, throbber

Can I style Drupal's AJAX Throbber and Progress Bar? What are the classes or ids to overwrite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Css styles you can use to theme the `throbber`:

- `.ajax-progress-throbber`
- `.ajax-progress-throbber .message`
- `.ajax-progress-throbber .throbber`

Also, take a look at [this post](http://www.antimath.info/css/change-throbber-in-drupal-7/).